# change column name pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to change the name of a column in a pandas data frame if it starts with a certain word.

e.e If column starts with DEP then change the full name to KEEP.

```
[col for col in df if col.startswith('DEP') then KEEP].
```

Comment: Why do you want duplicate column names? This is not recommend with Pandas (in fact, data analysis generally).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible, but not recommended, because get duplicated columns names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'DEP1':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'DEP2':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
  DEP1  B  C DEP2
0    a  4  7    a
1    b  5  8    a
2    c  4  9    a
3    d  5  4    b
4    e  5  2    b
5    f  4  3    b

df.columns = ['KEEP' if col.startswith('DEP') else col for col in df]
print (df)
  KEEP  B  C KEEP
0    a  4  7    a
1    b  5  8    a
2    c  4  9    a
3    d  5  4    b
4    e  5  2    b
5    f  4  3    b
```

So then if select column `KEEP` it return all duplicated columns in DataFrame:

```
print (df['KEEP'])
  KEEP KEEP
0    a    a
1    b    a
2    c    a
3    d    b
4    e    b
5    f    b
```

---

So if want filter all columns starting with `DEP` use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex `^` for starting string:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^DEP')
#alternative solution
#df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('DEP')]
print (df1)
  DEP1 DEP2
0    a    a
1    b    a
2    c    a
3    d    b
4    e    b
5    f    b
```

Comment: That `df.columns =` is crucial!

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot - yes understood about duplicates. but in this case its fine as I'm going to be adding them together if they have the same name

Comment: @fred.Schwartz, If you're going to sum the columns and then discard them, you don't actually have to rename them, just use `df['result'] = df[cols].sum(1)`. Where `cols` is your list/array of columns.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a callable to [**`rename`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'KEEP' if x.startswith('DEP') else x)
```

You can either reassign this to the name `df` or use the `inplace=True` argument.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't what you've requested, but I strongly recommend you keep characters *after* `DEP` to differentiate your column labels. The reason is much of Pandas functionality becomes unusable and you *lose* information by using duplicate labels.

One way is to use a dictionary mapping:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEP123': [1, 2, 3], 'Test': [4, 5, 6],
                   'DEP983': [7, 8, 9], 'Test2': [10, 11, 12]})

mapper = {col: f'KEEP{col[3:]}' for col in df.filter(regex='^DEP')}
df = df.rename(columns=mapper)

print(df)

   KEEP123  KEEP983  Test  Test2
0        1        7     4     10
1        2        8     5     11
2        3        9     6     12
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with jpp , do not using the duplicated column names

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('DEP','KEEP')
df
Out[866]: 
  KEEP1  B  C KEEP2
0     a  4  7     a
1     b  5  8     a
2     c  4  9     a
3     d  5  4     b
4     e  5  2     b
5     f  4  3     b
```